# Error 1935 while installing Office 2007 on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, installation, microsoft-office-2007

I am working on a Windows 7 x64 computer that started with an issue where Word 2007 would not open when clicking on a Word document in My Documents. After trying many fixes I decided to just reinstall Office 2007. When I get about 80% through the installation I get an **Error 1935**. I have tried all kinds of fixes, repairing and reinstalled .NET Framework, ran System Update readiness tool, and virus scans to no avail. At the same time, every time I run Windows Update now, I keep getting a message that I need to reboot the computer first before I can install any updates.

Please, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I had the same problem and found a [workaround](http://superuser.com/questions/1032377/error-1935-while-installing-microsoft-office-2007-and-i-have-net-framework-run/1032383#1032383).

Answer (score -1):

Some windows installer errors are because of temporary files, go to your temp folder and the one in Windows\Temp and delete all temporary files. Try again.