# Error 1935 while installing Microsoft Office 2007, and I have .NET framework running fine

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, .net-framework

Office 2007 Enterprise fails to install on my fresh Windows 7 64-bit, with "Error 1935 ... HRESULT: 0x80070BC9". The advice online is to [make sure .NET framework is installed](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-office_install/error-1935-when-installing-microsoft-office-2007/303b4ab8-abac-413b-8275-af358feef934), and it is - and running fine, for example paint.NET works.

Does it want some old .NET version perhaps?

[image: Office 2007 won't install]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem was with .NET Framework, but I re-installed in Custom mode, and made sure to uncheck any components that had ".NET" in the name:

- .NET programmability for Excel
- .NET programmability for Word
- .NET programmability for PowerPoint

I think these are the only ones.